# How to get the details of a file on Windows

Tags: windows, perl

If you open the properties of a file in Windows, there usually is a Details tab. I want to access the information on this tab, but I don't know how.
Is there a module for it? Does someone has a code sniplet?

I tried to work with Win32::File's GetAttributes, but these are not the attributes I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Win32::OLE;

my $objShell  = Win32::OLE->new("Shell.Application") or die;
my $objFolder = $objShell->NameSpace($myDir) or die;
my $objFile   = $objFolder->ParseName($fileName) or die;

while ( $i <= 34 ) 
{
  my $propertyName  = $objFolder->GetDetailsOf($fileName,$i);
  my $propertyValue = $objFolder->GetDetailsOf($objFile,$i);
  print "$i -- $propertyName -- $propertyValue\n";
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Things I noticed: for $myDir, the path has to be in the form with double backslashes (like c:\\mydir - c:/mydir won't work). Also, maybe better use foreach my $i ( 0 .. 34 ) instead of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate a COM `"Shell.Application"` object. It exposes a `.NameSpace(folder)` method that returns a reference to the name space of the indicated folder, which holds the information you need. The retrieved instance holds a `Items` collection with references to each of the files in the folder, and a `.GetDetailsOf(file,property)` to retrieve each of the values seen in the details tab and explorer columns.

Sorry i have no idea of perl, so i can not include any working code.