# How to retrieve custom attribute of text file using perl

Tags: perl, attributes, text-files

I have a text file and I am adding a custom attribute "email" to it via Java Files API.
Now, i would like to extract that attribute from a perl script.

after searching in internet, I came across the following code that retrieves owning user of a file

```
use Win32::OLE;
   my $objShell = Win32::OLE->CreateObject("Shell.Application");
   my $objFolder=$objShell->Namespace("c:\\temp") or die "$!" ;
   my $a = $objFolder->ParseName("Input.txt")  or die "$!" ;
   my $owninguser= $objFolder->GetDetailsOf($a, 10)."\n" or die "$!" ;
```

10 signifies owning user  in perl 5 and above.

I cant use Win32::File because it just retrieves constants in a OR-edformat

could someone throw some pointers on how to retrieve custom attribute on a text file.

BTW, I'm using Windows 7 64-bit & Active Perl 5.18.4.1803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an interesting one. My code is at the end.

I'm not really familiar with custom file properties but the below will iterate through all properties and stop when it encounters 2 blanks in a row or the desired key. When running it you will find that it does not list the custom property as it is not available through this interface.

This is based on the code at [How to get the details of a file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065947/how-to-get-the-details-of-a-file-on-windows)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;

my $fileName = 'test.txt';
my $myDir = 'c:\testing\e';

my $objShell  = Win32::OLE->new('Shell.Application') or die;
my $objFolder = $objShell->NameSpace($myDir) or die;
my $objFile   = $objFolder->ParseName($fileName) or die;

my $blank = 0;
# Apparently the numbers vary between OS versions, 300 is a guess
for ( my $i = 0; $i < 300; $i++ ) {
  my $propertyName = $objFolder->GetDetailsOf($fileName, $i);
  # skip when finding 2 blanks in a row, there may be a few more later.
  if ($propertyName eq '') {
        if ($blank) {
            last;
        }
        $blank = 1;
        next;
  }
  my $propertyValue = $objFolder->GetDetailsOf($objFile, $i);
    print "$i -- $propertyName -- $propertyValue\n";
}
```

So, after looking around the internet I don't think this is possible with plain Windows API calls (I could be very wrong about that).

This link shows that you can download `DSOFile.dll` from Microsoft in order to access custom properties: http://blog.rodhowarth.com/2008/06/how-to-set-custom-attributes-file.html

I've tried the perl code below, and it seems to work. I didn't dig too deep into the `Win32::OLE` documentation - there is probably a better way to access the information instead of a direct hash lookup.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;
use Data::Dumper;

my $obj = Win32::OLE->new('DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties') or die Win32::OLE->LastError;
$obj->Invoke('Open', 'C:\testing\e\test.txt', 0, 0); # constants found in headers
my $custom_property = $obj->{CustomProperties}{'myprop'}; # you would use 'email' here

my $custom_value = $custom_property->{'Value'};
print "Value is: $custom_value\n";

print "\nFile Object:\n", Dumper $obj;
print "\nCustom Property:\n", Dumper $custom_property;
```

You can also use the DLL directly but this tends to be really painful, so best avoided.

Comment: Thanks Nick,
I've already tried the first approach and couldnot retrieve my attribute. Sorry, I should have mentioned in the question.

I've downloaded the dll from Microsoft, pasted it at the same location where my perl file is present. but the scrips fails at 
    my $obj = Win32::OLE->new('DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties') or die 'error';

Comment: You need to use the installer so that your registry gets updated and it knows about DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties

Comment: The installer just extracts its contents. It is not doing anything else.
I've used regsvr32 to register the dll manually and even then perl script died at that new() line with message "died at line..."

Thanks for your help. I will try digging around for some time and get  back .

Comment: That's odd. Was it DsoFileSetup_KB224351_x86.exe from Microsoft? Can you find DSOFile if you search your registry? I'm also using Windows 7 64-bit. The only difference is I made a C# console application using the DLL first but I doubt that matters.

Comment: I was able to run the demo application provided by installer. the demo application wasnot able to read my custom attribute. so I think there is no way to read the custom attributes that were set using Java.
Thanks for your help Nick

Comment: Ah that's a shame. I thought it would be the same at the OS level. You could of course make a tiny Java program and call it from Perl but that's never ideal.

Answer (score 0):

DSOFile.dll cannot read custom attributes that were set using Java.
I came to this conclusion after spending two days on testing about 15 different files.
So Please do not try setting user-defined attributes in Java and reading them through perl.